# Linux camera device tree numbering

Tags: linux, video, webcam

I am trying to identify a `/dev/video<N>` camera by the USB `vendor:product` IDs and I learned that the [sysfs has that information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150016/162711), e.g.:

```
cat /sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/input/input17/id/vendor
cat /sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/input/input17/id/product
```

However, as you can see, in my example I have the child `.../input/input17/...` and that number seems to be different for all the cameras I have. There seems to be exactly one directory within `input`.

But can I rely on that, so that I can just use the pattern `input/input*/...`? Where can I learn more about the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a technically founded answer to my own question, but an observation which at least for me gives enough detail to identify the camer:

Connecting the camera gives in `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg
...
[48614.450392] usb 3-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
...
[48614.884939] input: HBVCAM camera: HBVCAM camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.2/3-2.2:1.0/input/input29
```

Note the `/input29` and note also that it says *"new high-speed USB device **number 30**"*. This maps to `/sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/input/input29/id/vendor` etc. The number `29` increases every time I disconnect and disconnect the camera. ***Number 30*** seems to be just the 1-based index of the same number, which can be also found in `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 030: ID 058f:3861 Alcor Micro Corp. VMware Virtual USB Hub
...
```

`Device 030` is my camera of interest, the number corrsponds to the (zero based) `input29`.

This confirms to me that I can just search in the `input/input*/` path and can assume that there is exactly one item in there, whos number I can ignore.
Or, if I know my `vid:pid` already, I can use `lsusb` to obtain the device number(s), and use that to find my path through the device tree.

Comment: If there are _any_ other devices on that bus, then the USB address and input number will likely get out of sync... I wouldn't connect the two.